# 'hhighlighter' wrapper script saying command not found

Tags: bash, terminal, bash-scripting, bashrc, kali-linux

I have gotten the wrapper script 'hhighlighter' from https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter which colors anything you want in stdout. I followed the instructions about installing ack-grep, created alias for ack=ack-grep in ~/.bashrc, put the h() function in ~/.bashrc, everything works fine when typing in the terminal. But when putting the EXACT same commands in a bash script, it says command not found. I will give examples here...

```
root@kali:~# echo "abcd" | h a b c d
abcd
```

Here is what my script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "abcd" | h a b c d
```

Exactly like the command typed in, but here is the output when running the script

```
root@kali:~# ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 1: h: command not found
```

How could this work when typing directly in the terminal, but not when having the exact same command in a bash script?

Comment: Does your script begin with `#!/bin/bash` ?

Comment: I reworked the question to hopefully make more sense

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it's been asked & answered at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169780/hhighlighter-wrapper-script-sayi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bng-command-not-found

Answer (score 1):

Solution that helped me was to force the script to run in interactive mode with a `#!/bin/bash -i` header.

Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide [warns](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html) about weird consequences though:

> Be aware that this can cause erratic script behavior or show error
>   messages even when no error is present.

However I haven't observed anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.bashrc` is only read during startup of an interactive bash session.

If you want it to always be read, put the name in the `BASH_ENV` environment variable:

```
export BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bashrc
```